# Laravel passport and socialite facebook login / authentication

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, authentication, token

Frontend: vue
Backend: laravel, laravel passport + socialite, mysql

At the moment the user is able to log in with email and password and get a personal access token to authenticate on our API. What we want to do now is be able to log in with facebook.

The user initiates the facebook login on the frontend and is redirected to our backend, at https://localhost/redirect/facebook. This then asks the user to authenticate our app, and we get a callback on out backend at https://localhost/callback/facebook.

From here i can get the users email, name etc. and model it to a User in our own system. And with passport i can create the personal access token tied to the user.

I am not sure of the callback is going to the right place. Currently it is going to the backend.

[Callback function on laravel backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9h64u.png)

Doing this the user is never returned to the frontend, and i am not sure where to go from here. One thing that i would like to do is redirect to our frontend with the newly creates personal access token, but i can't seem to find out how i do this.

Let me know if you need any more information, or further explanation of the problem. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: import `use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;` on top of your facebookcontroller. @AndreasBoegh

Comment: That's not it. Socialite is working i'm just not sure where to go from here to solve my problem. Do i have to send the callback from facebook to my front or backend? Currently it's going to my backend with the code and state.

i tried redirect to my vue frontend using with->(['token' => $token ]); but that seems not to work.